# Ionic 5: Custom Side menu

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4, ionic5

How can I made custom side menu in ionic 5  using Angular I want same side menu as I attach
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? On stackoverflow it is customary to first put in some time trying to solve the problem rather than asking for a solution from others right away. So if you could please post code of what you have done so far and what problems you are encountering it would help you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to start your project with the sidemenu template. Like this:

```
ionic start MyProject sidemenu [options]
```